# Windows batch file: is there a way to add an "and"?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

The short version: is there a way to to write an "and" or an "or" clause in a batch file?

The slightly longer version:

I've inherited a Visual Studio project that creates a dll and then copies that dll to another location.  As a post build step, VS runs the following script.

```
if not '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'DebugNoSvc' goto end

xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.config $(ProjectDir)..\myService\bin\Debug
xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.config $(ProjectDir)..\myService\bin\DebugNoSvc

:end
```

It looks like there's a problem when the project is compiled as Debug, since it doesn't do the copy (I'm guessing that at some point the middle section got updated, but the if clause didn't.)

Is there an easy way to do complex boolean logic in "if" clauses in batch?

Comment: I'm wondering, what you want, sounds more like an `OR` than an `AND`. The difference is significant since Beska answered in case of the `OR` which it sounds like you mean, and Kyle Alons answered in the case of the `AND` which you actually asked. So is what you want really `AND` or `OR`?

Comment: Well, it depends...I can really use either one depending on how I use NOT...in this case I asked for an AND so I could change it to something like IF NOT A AND NOT B GOTO END, but I could use an OR too, by saying IF A OR B DO COPY ELSE END.  Whatever.  I'm mostly just looking for whether complex boolean logic is available.  (Sadly, it looks like "no".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'Debug' goto test2

xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.config $(ProjectDir)..\myService\bin\Debug
goto end

:test2
if not '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'DebugNoSvc' goto end

xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.config $(ProjectDir)..\myService\bin\DebugNoSvc

:end
```

Comment: That is actually more like an `OR` clause, but I agree it seems like what he wants, even though he asked for `AND`

Answer (score 1):

With standard DOS batch processing, I think you need one of the multiple `if` statements as is already posted.  Another possibility is to use something like [JP Software's command processor](http://www.jpsoft.com/tcmddes.htm) Take Command.  They have a free version.  It is a vast improvement over a normal DOS shell and has a lot of very cool functionality including the ability to use `.and.` and `.or.` in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning to think that something like this might be the best solution, but I'm really not sure:

```
if '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'DebugNoSvc' goto copyDebugNoSvc
if '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'Debug' goto copyDebug
goto end

:copyDebugNoSvc
xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.config $(ProjectDir)..\hsspringhost\bin\DebugNoSvc
goto end

:copyDebug
xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.config $(ProjectDir)..\hsspringhost\bin\Debug
goto end

:end
```

Comment: That is actually more like an `OR` clause, but I agree it seems like what he wants, even though he asked for `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question directly: Yes, there's an "and" in Windows batch files (a/k/a NT shell) which allows you to do multiple things on the same line: the ampersand `&`. There's also a "grouping" option which allows you to treat a set of lines as a single entity: parenthesis `( ... )`.

```
echo Hello, world & if "%windir%"=="C:\WINDOWS" (
echo from Windoze
)
```

Not sure how that helps in your situation, though... I suspect that Beska's suggestion of `if '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'Debug' ...` might help, though.